# remove /web from url symfony 3.3 by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

i am working on symfony 3.3 application, i deploy it on server  it's working fine; now my problem is how to remove /web from my URL:

From this:

> http://www.example.com/web

To this:

> http://www.example.com/

For information, i had already found too many solution like changing in my apache conf, or from .htaccess

For me i want modify my htaccess not the apache conf

Can anyone give me the solution to my problem, i will appreciate that

Comment: Why would you upload it in the first place? I mean, upload only its contents into public_html and you should be good to go. Worked in my case.

Comment: I just want make every thing separated and structed

Comment: There is no difference in terms of clean structure between public_html/(files) and public_html/web/(files) unless you plan to put more files in public_html directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not have to change htaccess. I think you put everithing in public_html folder on server. No. Your web folder content should be in public_html on server. Other folders should be in the same as public_html. That way your url do not need /web. Do not worry for name of web folder change. Symfony is ok with it.

Comment: i want add .htaccess in root that can access to /web without put his content  in public_html and keep things structred cause i have lot of dir inside my /web